# How can I install Python 3.9 on a Linux Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I tried `apt install python 3.9` and it replied:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.9
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.9'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.9'
```

Comment: You can install Python 3.9 Alpha 5 from the [Deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+index). But be aware: it is an Alpha version. It can and will contain bugs and might be incompatible with many known packages.

Comment: I know this is an old question but for old ubuntu version the only way I found is the one related by  [@Akash Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6722799/akash-kumar) [https://stackoverflow.com/a/64353748/9794948](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64353748/9794948)

Answer (score 75):

If you are on [Ubuntu 19.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine)) (Eoan Ermine) (or any other version unsupported by the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)), you will not be able to install using the *deadsnakes* PPA.

What you can do instead, is get [the source](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.0/Python-3.9.0.tar.xz) from [Python's official website](https://www.python.org/), and install it manually, as described [here](https://opensource.com/article/20/4/install-python-linux).

To do so, first, install the dependencies required to build the Python package.

```
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev \
libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev \
libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev curl software-properties-common
```

Then download the tarball and extract it:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.0/Python-3.9.0.tar.xz
tar -xf Python-3.9.0.tar.xz
```

Then [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) to the extracted directory:

```
cd Python-3.9.0
```

Now configure the script:

```
./configure
```

Now, to install Python 3.9 alongside your current Python installation (if any), use:

```
sudo make altinstall
```

Lastly, you can verify your installation using

```
python3.9 --version
```

**How to make python3.X default of Python 3?** (Optional)

```
rm /usr/bin/python3
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

- create an alias in *~/.bash_aliases*, *~/.zshrc*, etc.

```
alias python3='/usr/bin/python3.9'
```

or

```
alias python3='/usr/local/bin/python3.9'
```

Comment: How to make it a default version for python3 ?

Comment: @raaj `python3` is symbolic link to some version of python, so you can 1) `sudo unlink /usr/bin/python3` 2) `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: This helped me a lot but then I found that I can't import `tkinter`.  The solution was to brute-force uninstall python3.9, `sudo apt install tk-dev tcl-dev` and then reinstall python3.9 as explained above. So, I suggest for anybody to add `tk-dev tcl-dev` to the list of packages to be installed in the first command of this answer.

Comment: Update. It also turned out that sqlite3 is not installed. Therefore, I believe the list of what should be installed BEFORE configuring and installing python from source should be: `sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev curl software-properties-common tk-dev tcl-dev libsqlite3-dev`

Answer (score 37):

You are getting that error because you first need to update the package list and the prerequisites.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

Then, add the repository *ppa:deadsnakes/ppa* to your sources list (where you will download Python from)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

Make sure to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when prompted. Then update available the packages:

```
sudo apt update
```

Lastly, install the version of your choice:

```
sudo apt install python3.9
```

Make sure to read this:

> Disclaimer: there's no guarantee of timely updates in case of security problems or other issues. If you want to use them in a security-or-otherwise-critical environment (say, on a production server), you do so at your own risk.

[PPA Deadsnake](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+index)

Comment: run `sudo apt update` before `sudo apt install python3.9`, or it still will not locate the package