# Python - AWS Lambda Function - Could not satisfied requirement

Tags: python, lambda, build, sam

I am just starting using AWS Lambda functions, and I come across this situation. I have the most basic python lambda function ( the Hello-World example ) generated from using `sam init` and when I use `sam build` I am receiving this error message :

'
Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - Could not satisfy the requirement: requests
'

The requirements.txt file contains only : `requests` and the tutorial used is here :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html

Please, help me with this situation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve it using the steps from this great tutorial : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-python-packages-for-aws-lambda-layers/

Right now, in AWS you have access to Python3.9, so you would have to install it in the docker image + the appropriate bitarray module

Python3.9 installation: Will's answer from :
[How to install python3.9 on linux ubuntu terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60824700/how-to-install-python3-9-on-linux-ubuntu-terminal)

This step also :
`pip install --upgrade setuptools` from : [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required#:%7E:text=I%20landed%20on,pip%20install%3A)

PS: `python -c 'import bitarray; bitarray.test()'` -> to test if the module is working